# Referenced DLL not copied

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a project (call it A, it's an exe) which references another project (call it B, it's a class library) which references a dll (call it C).  When debugging A.exe from visual studio I get a run time error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in B.dll.  Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'C', Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

When I go to my executing bin\debug directory, sure enough, C.dll isn't there.

I've explicitly called classes in C.dll from B.dll, so there isn't any weird run time adding of references or reflection being used to call it.  I've also set "Copy Local" to true on C.dll.  If I reference C.dll from A.exe directly, then it runs with no problem, but I'd rather not have to do that.

I've tried to repro the problem in a new solution, but I've been unable to.

Does anyone know what might be preventing this dll from copying to the final output directory?

Comment: How are you referencing `C` from `B`? Project reference?

Comment: @christiandev C is a reference to a dll

Comment: **call it C, also a class library**, when you add a reference to this from `B`, are you adding this as a reference to the build output from `C` or is this class library part of the solution, and you are referencing using Project reference?

Comment: @gunr2171 That doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: yes but what christiandev is probably asking is if you set a reference to C in your B library.

Comment: @christiandev C is NOT a part of the solution, so it is not a project reference.

Comment: @terrybozzio C is referenced by B via browsing to the dll.

Comment: @MikeH, Add C as a Project Reference to the library itself (which should be in the same solution). That will pull it along when you build B. If you just reference the plain dll, it will not copy it.

Comment: Check the MSBuild.  IME, weird stuff like things is often found nestled deep in some oddball statement stuffed in there.  Post anything suspicious or related to C.DLL here in the question.  Compare it to a working solution too.

Comment: So, C is actually a DLL, not a class library project.  `Project A` will need a reference to `C`

Comment: @christiandev yes, it is a DLL.  I guess I meant it was compiled as a class library.

Comment: if the class library is something you can add to your solution, that would be cleaner as you would always have the latest version (assuming this is under SC).

Comment: @christiandev I could, but I prefer to keep the number of projects to a minimum, there are already 30+ projects in this solution as it is.

Comment: Downvoter coming by a year later care to comment?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is have the projects `A`, `B`, and `C` all in one Visual Studio **Solution**, then you can reference the other projects that you need without referencing the dlls.

Once you have that, then add a Project Reference like this:

- project B references project C
- project A references project B

Because you are then referencing the *projects*, it will pull the necessary dlls along for the ride when you compile the whole thing.

However, as neo said, if you keep `C` as a dll, then `A` will have to reference it as well, because VS is not smart enough to copy it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ok finally got it...I think.

It looks like the C project didn't have any version information under Application-->Assembly Information.  It was also missing a guid.

For the record: You CAN reference the way I described (A refs B which refs C) and have the output copied.  I did go back to a dll reference rather than a project reference and it still worked after a clean and build.

I'm still not sure why I was able to get this to work in a new solution (before making changes), but I'm up and running now.

**Edit:**
One other note, it looks like there was no assembly.cs in the project (which is why it didn't have any version info).  I wonder if it was just a recompile of this project that could have fixed it rather than updating the assembly info.

Comment: I don't know why adding that information would make any difference, but whatever works...

Comment: If anyone does know I'd be happy to mark their answer as correct!

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered similar problems so I'd recommend to try these things:

- Toggle "copy local" to "false" and then to "true" again, it should resolve the problem, if the problem is missing 
       `< Private > True < /Private >` node in project file
- Check Target Framework of your project, I'have similar problem with several projects targeted "4.0 framework" and other "4.0 client profile", after switching to "4.0" on every project was resolved

Comment: Tried changing the copy local to no avail.  Framework is 4.5 on the main project and 2.0 on the other.  Thanks for the idea, that's bitten me before.